# Why doesn't Edge/16.17025 send referrers?

Tags: meta-tags, browsers, referrer, browser-support, microsoft

Does anyone know why Edge/16.17025 wouldn't send referrers?  Are there any registry keys or options to control this?  There are `meta` tags on the page that have `Referrer-Policy` set to `unsafe-url` and `Referrer` set to `always`.  The source and destination URLs are both HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `<meta name="referrer-policy" …>` has never been a standard nor a draft. So `<meta name="referrer-policy" content="unsafe-url">` was presumably ignored by *Microsoft Edge* 16.

And regarding [Referrer Policies](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-referrer-policy/#referrer-policies), [*Can I Use*](https://caniuse.com/https://caniuse.com/referrer-policy) reports that *Microsoft Edge* versions 12 to 18

> initially supported an early draft of the specification which can only use a meta tag and is only compatible with the `origin` value from the new spec.

(emphasis mine), which implies that `<meta name="referrer" content="always">` was also presumably ignored by *Microsoft Edge* 16.

In conclusion, *Microsoft Edge* 16 probably felt back to a default Referrer Policy that blocked referrer info. No idea of which setting you could have tweaked to counter this.